# shell script "syntax error: `done' unexpected."

Tags: shell, hadoop, hive

I am new to linux shell scripting, here is a snippet I want to use:

```
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
echo ""
echo ""
echo ""
echo "Counting the table : $line"
eval "hive -e 'select count(*) from $line'"
done < "$1"
```

I name it as *count_row.sh*.
Here is the usage:

```
$ ./count_row.sh t1.csv > row.txt
```

*t1.csv* basically contains some table's name each line.

I got an error below:

[image: syntax error at line 7: `done' unexpected]

But the snippet I borrowed here was marked as accepted solution, presumably it is correctly written. So what am I missing here? Thank you very much.

Comment: Any particular reason you're using `eval` here? It doesn't look like it's necessary.

Comment: Are you sure you're executing the same code as in your question? I copy pasted it to a new script on my machine and it works fine. (I just had to replace `hive` with `echo`)

Comment: @shambalambala hive is the command I need to use in hadoop to run the query and get the table's row count

Comment: I get the same result as *shambalambala*, using input `<(echo foo)`.  Perhaps the error specifically depends upon what `eval` does to the content of *t1.csv* when loaded as `$line`.  If so, we'd need a line from *t1.csv* that reproduces the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have table names each on their own line, that is a regular text file, not a *csv*, by the way.

Try not using `eval`, though, and instead run the statement inline.

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r line; do
  echo "${line}: $(hive -e 'select count(*) from ${line}')"
done < "$1"
```

If you want to test your script better, I would suggest a `for` loop over a hard-coded list of tables.